# On firebase DB, Redux duplicate last data from store

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I implemented web chat on react-redux, using firebase for real-time messages. Firebase always returns the last message object. When I refresh the page the last date is also added to the store and the last object is duplicated in redux.

How can I do it right so that after updating the page I’ll check the store if there is a duplicate message then do not add it to the redux?

**Messages.js**

```
const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user-data"));

useEffect( () => {
    if(userData.account_id) {
        firebaseDB.ref().child(API.firebaseEnv + "/messages/messageItem" + userData.account_id)
            .on("value", snap => {
                const dataMessages = snap.val();
                console.log(dataMessages)
                setTimeout(() => {
                    firebaseGetMessages(dataMessages);
                }, 2000);
            });
    }

}, []);
```

I tried to delete the session after fetching, but when I refresh page all data deleted

```
firebaseDB.ref().child(API.firebaseEnv + "/messages/messageItem" + userData.account_id).remove()
```

**Action.js**

```
export const firebaseGetMessages = ( messages ) => (dispatch)  => {
    // console.log('action:', messages)
    dispatch(firebaseMessageData(messages));
};

const firebaseMessageData = ( firebaseData ) => ({
    type: "FIREBASE_SET_MESSAGE_DATA",
    firebaseData
});
```

**Reducer.js**

```
export default function messages ( state = [], action = {}) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_MESSAGES_DATA':
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.messages,
                isLoading: false
            };
        case "FIREBASE_SET_MESSAGE_DATA":
            // console.log('state:', state.data);
            state.data.messages.push(action.firebaseData);
            return {
                 ...state,
        };
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: why u are mutating `state.data.messages` do not mutate

Comment: @xdeepakv I have all the messages added to the page from the store.data.messages, that why getting data i must merge with him

Comment: tes. use detructure: `state.data = state.data. messages.concat(action.firebaseData)`

Comment: TypeError: state.data.concat is not a function

Comment: update :D sorry!

Comment: state.data = state.data.messages.concat(action.firebaseData) - right ? same problem, concat is not fuction, i updated my file, please see

Comment: lol man.. u just copy pasted :( `state.data.messages = state.data. messages.concat(action.firebaseData)` sorry I keeping doing type understand code first before write :(

Comment: @xdeepakv I'm just starting to learn, maybe I will have funny mistakes, so I asked for help

Comment: what is the purpose to add on setTimeout??

`setTimeout(() => {
                    firebaseGetMessages(dataMessages);
                }, 2000)`

Comment: @xdeepakv When I get requests from firebase, it first goes as undefined and then I get the data, but as I did setTimeout everything worked for me

Comment: @xdeepakv Thanks, I read, do you think the problem is a duplicate date because of this?

Comment: yes.. most likly u get data in this call which is duplicate.. and I think this is push message . so update on interval. do don not have to fetch data again

Comment: @xdeepakv from the side of firebase will be if there is a duplicate he will not send it to me and the redux will not add it to store ? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: i added my ansswer, please check

Comment: @xdeepakv thanks, i will try and give feedback

Comment: @xdeepakv I checked with once (), but I can’t work in real time, I need to refresh the page for get data

Comment: @xdeepakv I did not understand your question

Comment: @xdeepakv I checked without setTimeout and get every step to the console. 1. data from the server - ok
2. data in action -ok
3. store - undefined

Comment: @xdeepakv i fix it, thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firebaseDB.ref().child` is `stream` of data, it will trigger automatically on data change. So whenever you push new data it will trigger and call the callback. If u want to read data for one-time use `once` the method. The sample is given below

**// Stream**

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
});
```

**// One time**

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
  // ...
});
```

More: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write